# NSView showing and hide SubView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

In my applications i need to display and hide based upon some user action, i have done following

In interface definition, have added views like that

```
@interface MyWnd : NSWindowController {

    MyCustomView1 *pCtmView1; 

    MyCustomView2 *pCtmView2;
}
```

In source file have following relevant methods

```
-(void)CreateSubViews{

    NSRect subViewRect = [self GetSubViewRect];

    pCtmView1 = [[ MyCustomView1 alloc]initWithFrame:subViewRect]

    pCtmView2 = [[ MyCustomView2 alloc]initWithFrame:subViewRect]

    initially both view will be hidden 

    [pCtmView1 setHidden:TRUE];
    [pCtmView2 setHidden:TRUE];

    [[self window] view addSubView:pCtmView1];
    [[self window] view addSubView:pCtmView2];
}

-(void)ShowSubView:(int)viewId{
  if(viewId == 0 ){
    [pCtmView1 setHidden:FALSE];
    [pCtmView1 setNeedDisplay:YES];
 }
 if(viewId == 1 ){
    [pCtmView2 setHidden:FALSE];
    [pCtmView2 setNeedDisplay:YES];
 }
}
```

In Init Application i am Calling ShowSubView:0 and its working fine, 
  but depend upon the some user action, i will call ShowSubView:1 and nothing is displayed & 
  EXEC_BAD_ACCESS i could see in the gdb
  Please guide me, do i need to do something more to display the view

Thanks

Comment: Try not calling setNeedsDisplay afterwards. Also, you should be using YES and NO instead of TRUE and FALSE. It's convention, though it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: It's `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, not `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`. The `EXC` stands for “exception”, here meaning a Mach kernel exception—i.e., your application crashed. Also, you may want to split `ShowSubview:` into two methods, one for each view. Chains of `if` statements make me nervous; I wonder what branch or branches the author (you) forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app crashes, look in the Debugger window—it'll tell you what your app was doing when it crashed.

You'll probably want to stop the debugger and re-run your app under Instruments's Zombies instrument. When the crash is because you messaged a dead object (which is the cause probably 80% of the time in Cocoa), the Zombies instrument will tell you what object that was and what killed it.